# Missing return statement Error

Tags: java, recursion, compiler-errors, return

I just started writing recursive methods. One of my methods for powers of ten is giving me a missing return type error.

```
public static double powerOfTen(int n)
{

 if (n == 0)
  return 1;

 if(n > 0)
  return (10 * powerOfTen(n - 1));

 if(n < 0)
  return (1 / powerOfTen(n - 1));

}
```

I'm pretty new so any explanation will be appreciated.

//////
Edit 
This worked out for me, for negative and positive powers of ten. Thanks for your help :D

```
public static double powerOfTen(int n)
{

 if(n > 0)
  return (10 * powerOfTen(n - 1));

 if(n < 0)
  return (1 / powerOfTen( (-1)*(n) ));


 return 1;

}
```

Comment: Possible bug in the last `if`: Shouldn't that involve `n + 1` rather than `n - 1`?

Comment: if(n < 0)
 return (1 / powerOfTen( (-1)*(n) ));
 
This worked for me

Comment: That would work. (`(-1)*(n)` can also be written as `-n`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
public static double powerOfTen(int n)
{
 if(n > 0)
  return (10 * powerOfTen(n - 1));

 if(n < 0)
  return (1 / powerOfTen(n - 1));

  return 1;
}
```

The compiler thinks it can't guarantee that there's always a value being returned since all the returns are in `if` statements. Doing it this way takes away the confusion

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not doing a range-coverage test so it doesn't notice that your code covers all possible values of int n, and thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code:

The point is clear: If that statement is `false`, I don't want the **function to continue**,so i'l `return` which you missed.

```
 public static double powerOfTen(int n)
    {
     if(n>1){             //check for positive n value
     if(n > 0){
      return (10 * powerOfTen(n - 1));
    }else if(n < 0){
      return (1 / powerOfTen(n - 1));
    }
    }
      return something;  //here error
    }
```

As a side note for best practices please use `{  }`  between `if else statements.`

Comment: Okay compiled fine. I ran a small test in the main. But I get a stack overflow error when I put in a negative integer for n. Seems to be looping infinitely. Help?

Comment: So please first check weather n is >1 or not.if n>1 then only it allwos to do the remaining stuff.updated my answer.

Comment: That solved the overflow, but the method returns 1.0 for any negative integer passed through.

Comment: and what your expecting??you are returning  1 right in the end so it converts into double that is 1.0. if negetivd input is there what you are expecting to return.?

Comment: If I pass through -3 I would expect it to return 0.001

Comment: I want the method to compute positive and negative powers of 10

Comment: so you have to change your logic inside.As of now this question is already answered.Try to change your logic or you may ask a new question.please mark it asnwer if you found helpful.good luck